# skip legend in for loop plot

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, legend

I have a plot which I put inside a for loop as following:

```
for i=1:300

    h3 = figure(3);
    hold on
    h3=plot(MC_Tx{:,i},MC_Ty{:,i},MC_Dx{:,i},MC_Dy{:,i},MC_Mx{:,i},MC_My{:,i})
plot(Mx_T,My_T,'-mo','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],'MarkerSize',5)
    h3 = title('Target and Missile Trajectory');set(h3,'Interpreter','latex');
    h3 = xlabel('Downrange [m]');set(h3,'Interpreter','latex');
    h3 = ylabel('Altitude [m] ');set(h3,'Interpreter','latex');
    grid on

    h4 = figure(4);
    hold on
    plot(MC_Time{:,i},MC_LAMBDT{:,i},MC_Time{:,i},MC_LAMBDD{:,i})
    h4 = title('$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$ and $$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$ vs Time');set(h4,'Interpreter','latex');
    h4 = ylabel('$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$ and $$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$ [rad/s]');set(h4,'Interpreter','latex');
    h4 = xlabel('Time [s]');set(h4,'Interpreter','latex');
    if i == 300
        h4 = legend('$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$','$$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$');set(h4,'Interpreter','latex');
    end
    grid on

end
```

However, most of the lines lay on each other and I can see only 1 of them which is the last ones.

How can I turn on legend only for the last line (Which means for i = 300) while having few figures in the loop?

Thank you!

Comment: What about an if test inside your for loop?

Comment: Thats actually an option! Wondering if there is another option tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

```
figure(4);
for i=1:300  
hold on
h(i)=plot(MC_Time{:,i},MC_LAMBDT{:,i},MC_Time{:,i},MC_LAMBDD{:,i})     
end
title('$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$ and $$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$ vs Time','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$ and $$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$[rad/s]','interpreter','latex')
xlabel('Time [s]','interpreter','latex')
legend([h(299) h(300)],{'$$\dot{\lambda_{T}}(t)$$','$$\dot{\lambda_{D}}(t)$$'},'interpreter','latex')
grid on
hold off
```

I don't have data to plot but I tried for you a simple example to visualize how the code works. If you run simple code like,(note only legend for lines 1 and 3 are presented)

```
figure(4);
x=1:5
for i=1:4    
h(i)=plot(x,x+i)
hold on
end
legend([h(1) h(3)],{'first','third'});
```

You get something[image]

Comment: I updated the question since I have more complex in real.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think the same idea for the solution for the previous can still be implemented. Did you try to implement? if yes what did you get?

Answer (score 1):

[`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) accepts a [graphics handle input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#inputarg_subset), so you can pass the plot objects (like the [Chart Line](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html) returned by [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)) after the loop concludes.

For example:

```
x = 1:10;

hold on
for ii = 1:10
    ls(ii) = plot(x, x*ii, 'DisplayName', sprintf('Plot %u', ii));
end
hold off

legend(ls(end-1:end))
```

Gives us:

[image: yay]

Note that I've utilized the [`'DisplayName'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html#property_d0e543354) property of the plot object, which allows you to generate a label for the data at plot time. This allows you to avoid having to hardcode labels later on and more easily supports dynamic legend creation.